# Why does a python program continue to write to the directory in which it was originally located, after I move the file to another directory?

Tags: python

I have 2 directories. I had a python program located in dir_1 writing to a .txt file also in dir_1. I meant to create them in dir_2, but when I move them both to dir_2, the python program, instead of writing to the existing .txt file that is now with it in dir_2, creates a new .txt file in dir_1 and writes to it. How do I fix this? I'm very new to programming and python and googling didn't help me out, probably because I didn't know what exactly to search.

```
with open('guest_book.txt', 'w') as file:
    while True:
        name = input('Please enter your name: ')
        if name == 'q':
            break
        else:
            print(f"Hello, {name.title()}!\nYou have been added to the guest"
                  f"book")
            file.write(f"{name.title()}\n")
```

Comment: Hi, please attach your code to your post so we know how are you creating the file.

Comment: Did did you remember to reload your `.py` file in your text editor from `dir_2` after moving it?

Comment: Please post the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: you  need to mention the exact path for e.g. in ur case dir_1/guest_book.txt

Comment: @Hussain is there a reason I didn't need to before I moved the files, but now I do?

Comment: @sprunner, what i understand as per your question is when you ran the python code from dir_1, the output text file is getting created in dir_1. On the other hand if you ran the same file in dir_2  but the output text file, instead of getting created in dir_2, is still getting created in dir_1. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Python writes to the file location you supply it with. If this file location is a relative path, then it will create files relative to the directory of the script. I.e. when you move the script then the `.txt` file will be created relative to the *new* directiory.

On the other hand, if you provide an absolute path, then it does not matter where the script is located / where you execute it from. Instead, it will create the file at that location always.

From the sounds of it, you are using an absolute path when you want a relative path.

So change from something like `/home/bob/file.txt` (Linux) or `C:\\Users\Bob\file.txt` (Win) to simply `file.txt` or even `./file.txt`.

---

Update: Since you were using a relative location all along, the problem will lie with the context that you are executing the script from. **Your code is not the issue here, it is how you are executing it.**

As vlovero suggests, maybe your IDE is not executing the new file in its new location?

One way you can test this robustly is to navigate to `dir_2` in a terminal and run

```
python your_program_name.py
```

This will execute the script in the `dir_2` location.

Comment: I just included the code from the program, I never changed the file path from guest_book.txt either before or after moving the files to the second directory.

Comment: That fixed the problem thank you! Now, so I know in the future, is there a reason my editor (pycharm) is doing this?

Comment: @sprunner An editor usually saves a temporary copy of the working file till you save it (CTRL-S). If you move the file on the disk, you need to delete the current working temporary file in the editor and open the file in the new location so that the editor knows to work in that new location. This is the default and expected behaviour of a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified an absolute path, your program is then specifying a directory relative to the *current working directory* (if instead, for example, you had specified a path such as `'../guest_book.txt`', you would have been specifying a directory one level above the current working directory). So let's imagine your OS is Linux and the Python program resides in `/my_home/programs`:

```
cd /my_home/data # this is the current working directory
python ../programs/your_program.py
```

The current working directory when the program is executed is `/home/my_home/data` even though the program being executed resides in `/my_home/programs`, and thus the output file will be created in the `/my_home/data` directory. [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=getcwd#os.getcwd) can be called to tell you what the current working directory is.